# Vuetify - Sync pagination with URL params

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify has a [Data table component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-pagination) which supports external pagination + sorting (via API).
What's the best way to sync these with URL params (2-way binding)?

---

*Example URL:*
http://localhost:3000/users?page=22

When I go to this link, I want to see **22** as the current page in the pagination.
When I click the Next button in the pagination component, I want to see the URL updated to http://localhost:3000/users?page=23

Comment: Are you using nuxt.js ?

Comment: @Mohsen No, I'm not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

1. Assocciate @pagination event to some method and 'page' prop whith data item.
2. In you method, set the url with window.history.pushState
3. In created() lifecycle hook, get query param from url and set it into data.

An example:

```html
<template>
<div>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
    @pagination="setQueryPage"
    :page="paramPage"
  ></v-data-table>
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
        return {
            headers: [
            {
                text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                align: 'start',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'name',
            },
            { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
            { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
            { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
            { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
            { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
            ],
            desserts: [
            {
                name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                iron: '1%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: '1%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Eclair',
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 23,
                protein: 6.0,
                iron: '7%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Cupcake',
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                carbs: 67,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: '8%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Gingerbread',
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 49,
                protein: 3.9,
                iron: '16%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Jelly bean',
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                carbs: 94,
                protein: 0.0,
                iron: '0%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Lollipop',
                calories: 392,
                fat: 0.2,
                carbs: 98,
                protein: 0,
                iron: '2%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Honeycomb',
                calories: 408,
                fat: 3.2,
                carbs: 87,
                protein: 6.5,
                iron: '45%',
            },
            {
                name: 'Donut',
                calories: 452,
                fat: 25.0,
                carbs: 51,
                protein: 4.9,
                iron: '22%',
            },
            {
                name: 'KitKat',
                calories: 518,
                fat: 26.0,
                carbs: 65,
                protein: 7,
                iron: '6%',
            },
            ],
            paramPage : 1,
        }

    },
    methods: {
       setQueryPage(paginationObject){
           let url = 'users?page='+ paginationObject.page
           window.history.pushState("", "", url);
        }
    },
    created(){
        console.log(this.$route.query.page)
        this.paramPage = parseInt(this.$route.query.page)
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: This assumes you have no other params in the URL like &sort=...

Comment: This is according to your example. You can adapt it to as many parameters as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I define a computed `page` variable operating directly on query param:

```
computed: {
  page: {
    get () {
      return parseInt(this.$route.query.page) || 1
    },
    set (page) {
      if (this.page !== page) {
        this.$router.replace({ query: { ...this.$route.query, page } })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And using it as `page` prop with `sync` modifier as follows:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="filteredUsers" :page.sync="page" />
```

This will work if table data is fetched before the table is displayed. If your data is loaded asynchronously, you'd need to reset the page (due to a bug?).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a librairie we made at my work: https://github.com/socotecio/vue-datatable-url-sync

It has an option and example to work directly with vuetify.

Working with vue 2 and 3. And has some useful parameters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33469332)